# How to change url to .html

Tags: php, url

I have an website where the search results show URL like

> http://mysite.com/index.php?SearchBox=Tum%20Hi%20Ho

How can I change the URL dynamically to something like

> http://mysite.com/tum-hi-ho.html

Please help.

Comment: which http server do you use? Apache? Consider using `mod_rewrite`

Comment: what have you tried?where do you want it to take effect either in browser address bar or just want to show it to your users by taking an input .And you should be aware with regular expression to deal with your urls in either case

Comment: .htaccess & rewrite rules

Comment: @Ankit I want it to take effect in the address bar of the browser.

Comment: You should definitly sanetize your variables. Seems like someone is messing around with your site already..

Comment: Thanks @JimL I just saw it!! I couldn't even think anyone from stackoverflow could try hacking my site!

Answer (score 1):

Use a .htaccess file when working on an Apache server, be sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

Try something along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/(.*).html$ ?SearchBox=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following links:

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html